# React state is updating but the component is not

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

There is a component that maps through an array stored in the state. A button, when it is clicked it updates the state, this action is working.

The problem is that the component is not updating too.

Here is the code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   ...
   const [fields, setFields] = useState([{value: 'test', editable: false},
                                         {value: 'test2', editable: false}]);

  ...

  const toggleClass = (id) => {
     const aux = fields;
     aux[id].editable = true;
     setFields(aux);
  }
  ...

  return (
     <div>
      ...
      {fields.map((field, id) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input className={field.editable ? 'class1' : 'class2'} />
              <button onClick={() => toggleClass(id)}>click</button>
            </div>
          );
      })}
     </div>
  );
```

I put logs and the state (`fields`) is updated after click to editable = true. But the css class is not changing.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: can you check whether the state is updating or not.
You can add console.log in useEffect

Comment: Make a copy of `fields` like so `const aux = [...fields];`. React needs different object references for rendering to work in case of non-primitives.

Comment: Don't mutate state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a copy of your existing state array, otherwise you're mutating state which is a bad practice.

```
const toggleClass = id => {
  const aux = [...fields]; //here we spread in order to take a copy
  aux[id].editable = true; //mutate the copy
  setFields(aux); //set the copy as the new state
};
```

Comment: Also, `fields` continues to point to the same underlying object, which is why the component doesn't re-render.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are mutating the value of `fields`, which makes it unsure for React to decide whether to update the component or not. Ideally if you should be providing a new object to the `setFields`.
So, your `toggleClass` function should look like something below:

```
const toggleClass = (id) => {
const aux = [...fields]; //This gives a new array as a copy of fields state
aux[id].editable = !aux[id].editable;
setFields(aux);
```

}

BTW, I also noticed that you're not assigning a `key` prop to each `div` of the the map output. Its a good practice to provide `key` prop, and ideally keep away from using the index as the key.